# integrate the webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html of three.js example to ASP.NET WebForm(mtlLoader.setPath failed)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I integrate the webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html of three.js example to ASP.NET WebForm.
But I meet a problem when I run the html, Visual Studio 2015 seem to be failed at mtlLoader.setPath.
Does somebody meet the same problem？
Another problem I cannot use Visual Studio 2015 to debug the javascript.
When I put a breakpoint in Visual Studio 2015, it appear "the breakpoint will not be hit no symbols loaded".

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'ObjModels3D/male02/' );
mtlLoader.setPath('ObjModels3D/male02/');
mtlLoader.load( 'male02_dds.mtl', function( materials ) {

materials.preload();

var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
objLoader.setPath('ObjModels3D/male02/');
objLoader.load( 'male02.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.position.y = - 95;
    scene.add( object );
}, onProgress, onError );
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved the problem by setting Web.Config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mtl" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dds" mimeType="image/x-dds" />
    </staticContent>        
</system.webServer>
```